# What Are Some Historical Applied Stats Problems

Tags: history, paradox

What are some interesting, historical applied statistics problems ?   i.e. sometime in the past that statistics have been used to affect the course of events?

The kind of problems I am looking for are things like

- German Tank Problem - bayesian statistics applied to estimate number of enemy tanks
- Florence Nightingale - showing that disease is the largest killer
- Abraham Wald Memo - armor the parts of the airplanes that do not have holes in them (selection bias)

I have been able to find a lot of classic statistic "paradoxes"   like the 2 envelope problem, or the 2 daughters problem.  But not that many actually applied.   I am interested in the paradox problems only in so much as they are historically relevant for instance.

- Monty Hall Problem -  great "paradox", and interesting because of its famous use an an actual game show

to clarify,  the examples I gave were war & destruction themed.  But I would be just as interested in a clever example of a company exploiting stats to make money.

Thanks!

Comment: There are multiple reasons to close this question, as appealing is it might be: it is too broad, it does not fit the framework of this site, it is vague, and it solicits opinion (what exactly does "interesting" mean?).  It would be a nice subject for a chat.

Answer (score 0):

- In the 60s a Bayesian search methodology was used to find [the lost submarine USS Scorpion.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_search_theory#USS_Scorpion)
- "Big Data" has revolutionized many industries including [sports](http://www.forbes.com/sites/bernardmarr/2015/03/25/big-data-the-winning-formula-in-sports/#83f3c5126dc9) and [marketing](http://www.forbes.com/sites/gregsatell/2014/10/12/the-future-of-marketing-combines-big-data-with-human-intuition/#4d2007884331); changing their course forever.
- The Los Alamos National Laboratory has been able to [predict flu outbreaks](http://www.lanl.gov/discover/news-release-archive/2015/May/05.14-predicting-flu-outbreaks.php) based on Wikipedia page views - potentially saving lives.